# ViewBox FontSize Issue

Tags: wpf, binding, font-size, viewbox

I am attempting to use a ViewBox to adjust the font size for different controls and not the control size itself. The problem is that whenever I put a control like a TextBox or ComboBox it'll resize the font properly, but the control will not stretch. I know this has to do with the 'infinite' amount of space the ViewBox can use.

I tried a different approach to where I had TextBlock inside of a ViewBox and bound another controls fontsize to that TextBlock.

```
<Grid Width=100>
    <ViewBox>
        <TextBlock Name=aTextBlock />
    </ViewBox>
</Grid>

...

<Grid>
    <TextBlock FontSize={Binding ElementName=aTextBlock, Path=FontSize}/>
</Grid>
```

This approach did not work. It would be nice if I could bind to the ActualFontSize but that does not exist.

One last approach was to use a ViewModelBase that bound the FontSize of `aTextBlock` to a variable and have the other textblock to that fontsize.

```
private double _currentFontSize;
public double GlobalFontSize
{
    get { return _currentFontSize; }
    set
    {

        _currentFontSize = value;
        MessageBox.Show(_currentFontSize.ToString());
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** I tried using int, double, and FontSize types for this class.

```
<Grid Width=100>
    <ViewBox>
        <TextBlock Name=aTextBlock
                   FontSize={Binding GlobalFontSize,
                                     UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                                     Mode=TwoWay} />
    </ViewBox>
</Grid>

...

<Grid>
    <TextBlock FontSize={Binding GlobalFontSize}>
</Grid>
```

And this did not work either. I'm starting to feel like the ViewBox is more trouble than it's worth. If I am doing any of this incorrectly or if anyone has any recommendations I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: Not quite sure I understand the objective, you want to adjust the font size *and* have the control resize to "match" the increased font size?  If so, then how big would you expect the control to get relative to the font size?

Comment: @CodingGorilla My application will be used on both, tablets, and desktops. The problem with the tablets is the resolution is high and the screen is small. This causes difficulty when using a finger to enter data. If I increase the size of the controls the font size stays at the default 12.However, if I put the control in a `ViewBox` the `FontSize` increases but the control no longer stretches to the cell it is in. So I attempted the global font size but it cannot inherit from a ViewBox FontSize.

Comment: Ok, so the problem is that he control will no longer resize when the window resizes, the `ViewBox` remains a fixed size?  Sorry, I'm trying to understand the problem.

Comment: @CodingGorilla once the control is placed inside of the ViewBox it resizes just fine. It just can no longer HorizontalAlignment="Stretch". It's for aesthetic purposes. I don't want a textbox growing in width/height as I type. I want the textbox to be of fixed width but also shrink grow with the application window size. That includes the font size.